# elementary OS doesn't shut down

Tags: kernel

I've got elementary OS 0.4 Loki and it doesn't shut down (black screen with white cursor). The same sometimes occurs with screen lock. Touchpad is sometimes turning off and sometimes the Linux bricks.

I've looked dmesg a few times, but how can I repair it?

dmesg: http://pastebin.com/mnYWMUZM

Kernel version: 4.8.0-040800rc8-generic. (I can't install older kernel than 4.8, because x.org server is bugged and it's making my fans spin very fast)

Comment: Looks like your Xorg is causing a kernel panic. This is not a stock elementary kernel right? What hardware are you using?

Comment: Asus Zenbook ux501vw. Newest default elementary kernel is 4.4, which making my fans spin very fast.

Comment: Do you know exactly what is causing your fans to spin up?

Comment: I suppose there are some drivers missing. I've found x.org logs http://pastebin.com/p6SmrgfD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by Paradise [at Elementaryforums](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/elementary-os-not-running-properly.2081/#post-2650) (paraphrased):

> I had the same 100% fan-speed issue with my Asus notebook. There is a workaround for this: just add `acpi_osi=!` in your GRUB. While booting with kernel 4.4, press "e" for "edit" and type in like this:
>
> [image: Linux_GRUB_Kernel_options_set_nomodeset_modeset_acpi2-GRUB]
>
> After booting, the fan control works correctly but now you must add this workaround in `/etc/default/grub` ... for future reboots:
>
> [image: etc_grub_default]
>
> `sudo apt-get install gedit`
>
> `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
>
> `sudo update-grub`
>
> ... Kernel 4.4 is more stable and tested

Answer (score 1):

Found answer here (missing some arguments in grub): https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/elementary-os-not-running-properly.2081/#post-2650

Comment: Glad you could find a solution and thank you for posting it here as well. It's a shame that a lot of hardware has a gimped ACPI implementation.